# Building image on virtual raspberry

Tags: raspbian, buildroot

I need to reinstall my raspberry; I have a problem with bind missing libraries, and I have failed to solve the issue.

But the raspberry is in use, tallying power and water usage, so I would hate the downtime; it takes ages to reinstall.

Is it possible on a linux or windows to have a virtual raspberry to build an image with the extra software and configuration, so I only have to "burn" a new sd-card and swap into the machine?

Comment: I have seen emulation stuff for linux to mimic the arm processor, but have not been able to get it to work myself. I think it would be worth $35 to have a second pi rather then deal with the headache of trying to run it as a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi foundation doesn't use buildroot. It uses a set of bash scripts and qemu-user. qemu-system started seriously considering Raspberry Pi support in 2016. Guides written before this date do not emulate the Raspberry Pi, but a superficially similiar "Versatile PB" board. It works ... i guess.

You have three options.

- Modify the foundation buildsystem. It already works. Obviously Linux-only: https://github.com/RPi-distro/pi-gen
- Play around with a version of QEMU newer than 2.6 , which emulate the Raspberry Pi.
- Use the "Versatile PB" emulation of QEMU. Don't forget to replace the kernel.